# mysql : Can I recreate a table using select, innerjoin and where clause in a single step?

Tags: mysql, create-table

I am new to using mysql workbench, and really need a simple data extraction script (post which I will be back in the land of the free i.e. python)

The idea is to create a new table by joining two pre-existing tables on an id, and applying a where clause. IS the following alright? or do I need to first apply the where clause and then do the create and join?

Here is attempt number 1 (which did not work).

```
CREATE TABLE `mysql`.`new_tbl`(
SELECT a.* , b.*
FROM mysql.tbla a INNER JOIN mysql.tblb b
ON a.id = b.id
where b.category='Z'
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use views, I think it most approaches what you're idealizing.
You'll find syntax details [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html).

For your specific situation, you shall run

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM mysql.tbla AS a
INNER JOIN mysql.tblb AS b
  ON (a.id = b.id)
WHERE b.category = 'Z';
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting views !- it appears to be faster ( I am gussing its just creating a view and only extracts data when queried).

Comment: You're welcome (:  
But I have some warnings. About tables "tbla" and "tblb", you must alias fields with same name (e.g. id columns). And remember that views are not always the best solution. You should also index fields involved in your joins.